# use + instead of %2B

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, instagram

I'm building an instagram app in rails. The oauth requires a string of scopes with `+` separating them in the url. However I've noticed rails converts the `+` to `%2B` which is causing my app authorization to fail.

How can I use the `+` symbol in a rails url instead of `%2B`?

**Edit**

The code:

```
redirect_to Instagram.authorize_url(:redirect_uri => CALLBACK_URL, :scope=> "comments+likes")
```

also take a look at the bottom of http://instagram.com/developer/authentication/ to see what I'm talking about.

Comment: No code examples at all? Please help us help you by providing these.

Comment: Why not just send spaces, which should become a plus in a querystring?

Comment: @ryanbigg I didnt think it required code. I've updated it.

Comment: @jasonTrue perfect that works thanks. Please post an answer so I can give you credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just send spaces between each item, which should become pluses in a querystring?